# How do I package a PWA site as a UWP app?

Tags: uwp, progressive-web-apps

I have tried to follow the instructions in and created a new project "Windows Application Packaging Project" (see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps/windows-features#set-up-and-run-your-universal-windows-app) but I run into an issue on step 2. After creating the project in the Application Tab I do not see "Start Page" text entry, instead I see "Entry Point". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not see "Start Page" text entry

Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps/windows-features#set-up-and-run-your-universal-windows-app) step 3,

> Under the **JavaScript** > Windows Universal category, select Windows Application Packaging Project. If you're using a previous version of Visual Studio, you can find the equivalent template under Hosted Web App (Universal Windows) or Progressive Web App (Universal Windows).

You need select uwp template under Javascript directory.

[image]

Comment: Dohh!! Didn't matter how many times I read it, I always missed the 'Javascript' reference. Thanks.

Comment: Is this possible with Visual Studio 2019 too?

Comment: @JasMich.de They removed the JS/UWP support in VS2019.  According to Microsoft "PWA and JavaScript UWP are the same thing".

Answer (score 0):

no unfortunatly they have removed vs2019 uwp pwa templates..
as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61199238/10446975)

> all templates (.jsproj) used to build UWP applications using Javascript have been removed